# Bind control to dynamic collection of key-value pairs

Tags: c#, wpf, datasource, visual-studio-2013, blend

I have a network service that provides a number of key-value pairs. The collection is huge and the available keys are changing over time. My goal is to be able to bind to this collection in either Visual Studio 2013 or Blend using the properties window in design mode (or intellisense in XAML). This of course requires the service client object to somehow be initialized during design mode to connect to the service and expose the keys as bindable properties.

I have been searching a lot about "ObjectDataSource" but my problem is that I cannot dynamically change the properties of this object.

What type of object should I choose as my data context?
How can I populate it during design mode?

Any ideas or suggestions towards how this could be implemented would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your data context to any object - you get dynamic updates if

- the object implements INotifyPropertyChanged (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
- or is observable (like ObservableCollection<> (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)).

If your goal is to create an observable dictionary, have a look at this post: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/

The object data provider can have it's data source set to any object too - the dynamic updates will occur if the object is as stated above. In addition, you can declaratively set the objectDataSource's values in xaml - but this doesn't appear to be something you want to do.
Note: You don't change the properties of the object data source - you change the object that it is wrapping for you.

If you want to be able to control the selected item of something like a list (a bit like the Winforms BindingSource)- take a look at ICollectionView (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be created by wrapping up your actual data source (same observable rules apply to get dynamic updates) using CollectionView (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview(v=vs.110).aspx)

So - to answer the rest of your question, one solution is to create an observable collection of observable objects (wrapping your key value pairs) and set that as your data context (or set it as your objectDataProvider's source, and bind your Xaml accordingly. This isn't the only way, but a quick google will show you others.

Edit Design mode
For design time data - look at using the design mode flags - an example is here: http://www.arrangeactassert.com/how-to-use-designdata-to-populate-controls-with-design-time-data-in-silverlight-and-wpf/

A list of (Silverlight design time attributes): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

I've never actually tried the design time stuff, so that's all I got!

Hth.

Comment: Hi Jay, I understand how this would work during run-time, but my problem is that I want to fill my ObservableCollection with key/value pairs in Visual Studio "Design mode". I want to be able to choose among the keys in the WPF editor / properties panel.

Comment: @Chrille Updated my answer with some design time data binding links - this is stuff I have never tried - so hope this points you in the reight direction.